# Java paint error during maximizing JFrame

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jframe, paint

I've following code to paint in `JFrame`.

```
package march_2013;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Question7 extends JFrame {

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        int[] x = new int[] { 10, 60, 360, 410, 210, 210, 260, 210, 190, 160,
                190, 190 };
        int[] y = new int[] { 200, 250, 250, 200, 200, 180, 180, 100, 100, 160,
                160, 200 };
        g.drawPolygon(x, y, x.length);
        g.drawLine(190, 100, 190, 180);
        g.drawLine(210, 100, 210, 180);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Question7 window = new Question7();
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setBounds(440, 40, 420, 400);
        window.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

It works fine gives following output.

[image]

But I maximize the JFrame, the image is repainted. But old image remains as it.

[image]

How to solve this problem? Thank you!

Comment: 1) Instead of painting in a top level container such as `JFrame`, add a `JPanel` & do custom painting in the `paintComponent(Graphics)` method.  Also return a sensible preferred size for the custom component, to assist the layout manager. 2) Don't set the size of top level containers.  Instead layout the content & call `pack()`.

Comment: ok.... i'll this way too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invoke `super.paint()`.

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    // ...
```

The [API document of paint](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#paint%28java.awt.Graphics%29) said:

> If this method is reimplemented, `super.paint(g)` should be called so that lightweight components are properly rendered.

To make sure the background is white:

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    // ...
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You should be calling `super.paintXxx`
2. You should avoid overriding the `paint` method of the top level containers (like `JFrame`) and instead, using something like `JPanel` and override it's `paintComponent` method.  The main reasons are; 1- top level containers aren't double buffered, meaning you will get flicker as the component is repainted. 2- you can prevent other content from been painted correctly (like not calling `super.paint`.

Check out [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for more details